# ExtJs 4.1-Adding a tab to tabbar view by clicking a tree node in another view

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a menu navigation view (MenuNavigationV), and I have a listener as well added to  handle the click events on the tree node. When I click a node I should be able to open/add a new tab panel to a tab bar if not available already in another view(MainV). How can I get a reference of MainV in MenuNavigationV?

My configuration is as follows

Viewport-dockeditems:headerview
        -panel
             -menuview
        -container
             -mainview

Answer (score 0):

Why not use id to reference by it, like Ext.getCmp('MainV').

You can also reference by relative paths, like

```
Tree: {
  ...

  listeners: {
    itemclick: function(tree, record) {
      tree.up('viewport').down('tabpanel').add({ Your item config here });
    }
  }
}
```